# Ruby reserved class method names

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, are there any methods that are reserved or have default meanings? I recently discovered that `initialize` is one. Are there any others that I should be aware of when naming my methods? (VI is not giving me the coloring clues that other IDEs give for reserved names.)

In particular, names that have meaning in other languages like `run`, `main`, `toString`, `onExit`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always see a list of the methods implemented by default for every class:

```
class Try
end

t = Try.new
puts t.methods.sort
```

EDIT: actually you may also want to look at the private methods (where `initialize` is):

```
puts t.private_methods.sort
```

Comment: It's not quite that simple :) Basically you can override every method in Ruby, but you shouldn't, unless you know what you are doing (ie. Meta-programming).

Comment: t.methods did not return anything but I assume it would if I addded anything to the class. t.private_methods was very informative however. Thanks!

Comment: @jbr Accidental overrides are exactly what I am attempting to avoid.

Comment: @jbr of course you can. You can do almost anything in ruby, but from the question I got OP wanted a list of methods already present.

Answer (score 2):

Also check out the list of reserver keywords [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/Rubysreservedwords.htm)

If you're working in Rails, you may also want to take a look at [this list](https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you should be aware of those:

[`keywords`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/)

Answer (score 0):

Despite nothing prevents declaring methods like `public` or `private`, I highly do not recommend doing so with any of the method names defined in core classes, such as `Object` and `Module`. Otherwise weird things can happen:

```
class Message
  def self.private
    puts 'private'
  end

  private
end

Message.private
```

Output:

> private
>   private

Private class method of a class `Module` was redefined as public.